# Load multiple images with different paths

Tags: java, eclipse

so i try to load two images from the same path but with different names.
if i copy the path directly from the image everything work fine.
but if i try to build the path from the system only one of them work(img1).
i've try couple of different ways i found in the internet to build the path but the results are the same.

what can cause this problem?

```
public void loadImages(String nm) {
    File f = null;
    BufferedImage image = null;

    System.out.println("read img:");

    String pathName = PICTURE_PATH + this.getMyColor().toString().toLowerCase() + nm;

    // read successful this img path.
    try {
        f = new File(pathName + "North.png");
        f.canRead();
        System.out.println("\nimg1 path:" + f);
        System.out.print("img1 absolute path:" + f.getAbsolutePath());
        img1 = ImageIO.read(f);
        if (!f.canRead())
            throw new IOException("Cant read the first file");
        if (!f.exists())
            throw new IOException("Cant find the first file");
        System.out.println("Successful read img 1");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error:" + e);
    }

    // got here exception error for this img path.
    try {
        f = new File(pathName + "East.png");
        System.out.println("\nimg2 path:" + f);
        System.out.println("img2 absolute path:" + f.getAbsolutePath());
        if (!f.canRead())
            throw new IOException("Cant read the second file");
        if (!f.exists())
            throw new IOException("Cant find the second file");

        img2 = ImageIO.read(f);
        System.out.println("Successful read img 2");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error:" + e);
    }
    System.out.println("Done.");
}


//this is the relevant output for this function:
//read img:
img1 path:src\icons\‏‏silverCarNorth.png
img1 absolute path:A:\Tools\eclipse\WorkPlace\HW1\src\icons\‏‏silverCarNorth.png
Successful read img 1

img2 path:src\icons\‏‏silverCarEast.png
img2 absolute path:A:\Tools\eclipse\WorkPlace\HW1\src\icons\‏‏silverCarEast.png
Error:java.io.IOException: Cant read the second file
Done.
```

Comment: You might want to add a diagnostic to check that the file actually exists before you try to read the file, i.e. `if(!f.exists()) throw new IOException(...); img = ImageIo.read(...);`

Comment: i did as you suggest and it's really cant cant find the second file.

Comment: Hmmm are you **absolutely** certain it's there! Suggest you also check the file can be read using `f.canRead()`. Also can you dump out the paths and post them? i.e. `System.out.println(pathName + "East.png")` for both files and cut-and-paste em.

Comment: first yeah im 100% know the files there in the same folder. second after using f.canRead() cant read the second file, and i added the result to the post.

Comment: tBTW ry `System.out.println("\nimg2 path:" + f.getAbsolutePath())` (kind of strange reading from `src`)

Comment: System.out.println("\nimg2 path:" + f.getAbsolutePath()) added to the code and i added the result to the post.

Answer (score 0):

so its appear the images had some extra characters..
the site not support this kind of characters so i add a print screen from the cmd.
this is the logs from the cmd:
[cmd logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okhy7.png)

so i had to rename the files and delete the  extra characters manually with the windows command line.
and after that everything works just fine!

Comment: this probably should have been an edit to the question, instead of an answer... just write a recursive method, which lists dirs and reads files. the prefixed pe? should not matter then. UTF-8 can certainly display Iwrith letters, while they are properly encoded... and if you cannot access these files, it might also be an encoding problem (they look the same, no matter how they are being encoded). ףףף

Comment: You're right i should had mentioned that i rename the files and everything work fine now, thanks for the help. and btw eclipse suggest me to save as UTF-8 and i did try it.. but without success to read them.

Comment: the source-code and the characters in the filename both need the same encoding... then their char-values will match and so the filename will match. code-page 862 and UTF-8 won't ever match. just see above, I can enter them on here... but only in UTF-8 encoding. picking up the filenames from a directory listing written in Java should still make them match. `String.toCharArray()` shows the difference.